# Are there any rewards for reaching a certain Elo rank?

Tags: league-of-legends

Will reaching a certain Elo ranking give you any type of award? If so, how does it work?

Comment: Indirectly related, but if you have a high Elo you can probably win a local tournament and receive RP and the Tournament Ryze skin.

Answer (score 2):

Last season, people got a border around their summoner profile depending on their rating (Bronze, Silver, Gold, Plat). Gold and Plat players got an exclusive Jarvan skin called "Victorious Jarvan IV". As well as a forum badge.

Edit: Not sure what they will plan for season two, but it is still young, so don't expect anything for awhile.

Comment: Could you add a link to the announcement for the Victorious Jarvan skins?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't give any rewards. There is a ladder (ranking) and you get to see how you are doing compared to others. People also got borders around their avatars at the end of last season.